# Entry point not found in dynamically loaded dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

In my windows application i have to load a dll dynamically. I achived this by DllImport attribute. But when i execute the command in Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio  **dumpbin /exports** on a DLL only 5 functions listed. I can't see my required function .But i can aceess the method when static linking. Is there any way to access the required function dynamically.

Comment: If the dll is your own... are you sure that this entry point is public?

Comment: No its not my own dll.

Comment: I suppose the question still remains.. is it a public method?

Comment: Yes it is public. I can access the method when i statically load the dll.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call functions in a DLL that are exported. If this is your DLL then you need to recompile it to export the functions that you need to call. If it is not your DLL, and the function is not exported, then you are out of luck.

You state in comments that the function can be called when you link to the DLL statically. That means that the function is exported. Its name is likely mangled or decorated so that you do not recognise it. Once you can work out what the mangled or decorated name is, you will be able to link to the function with runtime linking.

Another possibility is that the function is exported from a different DLL, or perhaps even defined in a static lib. Without more details we cannot give you anything much more definitive than this.

Comment: So i have to load the dll statically and access the required method??

Comment: No. If you can link to the function with static DLL linking you can link to it at runtime too. Do note that the question makes no mention of static linking. That information appears only in comments. Perhaps you should edit the question.